# Erro ao usar o pandas no pycharm para ler arquivo excel

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

[image: Erro]

estou tentando usar o pandas no pycharm para ler um arquivo excel mas me retorna muitos erros como aparece na imagem, já tentei mudar o caminho do arquivo,usar o r antes do caminho, enfim nada da certo e não acho ninguém com erro semelhante.

Comment: você tentou usar a extensão: teste.xlsx ?

Comment: tentei sim, o erro continua o msm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualizei o pycharm 2 vezes pois ele estava pedindo, depois instalei o xlrd e openpyxl ( através do pip install )porque o pycharm também tava pedindo e deu certo, não sei exatamente qual desses resolveu o problema mas deu bom :)